# How to alert if no value selected in Autocomplete combo box in react js?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, default-value

I have combo box function:

```
function comboBox(props) {
        const options = ['z','y','x']
        var va;
        
        return (
            <div style={{height:'100vh',backgroundImage: `url(${back})`, backgroundSize: 'cover', marginTop: '-8vh'}}>
            <div style={{height:'100vh', textAlign: 'center', alignItems: 'center', direction: 'rtl'}}>
            <h1 style={{marginTop: '8vh', marginLeft: '-10vh', paddingTop: '10vh'}}>hoose</h1>
            <Autocomplete style={{borderStyle: 'groove', borderWidth: 'Thick'}}
                options={options}
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                defaultValue={options[0]}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => options[0]}
                onChange={(event, value) =>va=value}
                renderInput={(params) =>
                <TextField {...params} variant="outlined"  style={{paddingRight: '90vh'}}/>}
            />
            <button style={{backgroundColor:'#f4eae0', height: '10vh', width:'52vh', marginTop: '28vh', marginRight: '10vh'}} onClick={() => getApi(va)}>go if a value selected)</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

which give me a combo box with 3 options to choose, and a default value- the first option.

but if I go ahead without choosing any value, based on my default setting- I will get undefined as selected value allthought I see the first option in the combo box. why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is around the way you are saving val. Because you are using React you should be saving it within a state and the value should come from there. If you want to check if there isnt a value, you just add a check within the onChange event.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

const options = ['z', 'y', 'x']

function comboBox(props) {
    const [val, setVal] = useState(options[0])

    return (
        <div
            style={{
                height: '100vh',
                backgroundImage: `url(${back})`,
                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                marginTop: '-8vh',
            }}>
            <div
                style={{
                    height: '100vh',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    direction: 'rtl',
                }}>
                <h1
                    style={{ marginTop: '8vh', marginLeft: '-10vh', paddingTop: '10vh' }}>
                    choose
                </h1>
                <Autocomplete
                    style={{ borderStyle: 'groove', borderWidth: 'Thick' }}
                    options={options}
                    style={{ width: 300 }}
                    value={val}
                    onChange={(event, value) => {
                        if (value === null) {
                            alert('no value')
                        }
                        setVal(value)
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            variant="outlined"
                            style={{ paddingRight: '90vh' }}
                        />
                    )}
                />
                <button
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#f4eae0',
                        height: '10vh',
                        width: '52vh',
                        marginTop: '28vh',
                        marginRight: '10vh',
                    }}
                    onClick={() => {
                        if(val === null){
                            alert('no value provided')
                        } else {
                            getApi(val)
                        }    
                    }}
                >
                    go if a value selected)
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or alternatively you could add a useEffect that has a dependency of val which would trigger whenever you change the autocomplete and do the same check I have done in the onChange

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if(val === null){
      alert('no value')
    }
  }, [val])
```

Comment: I did as your first suggestion and still not working

Comment: I just did an edit to the button onClick which does the same thing. I just ran in all in a codebox and it worked fine. Also I recommend not using vh for things like margins and paddings.